# cakephp certificate printing Image to PDF writer and replace contents

Tags: cakephp, pdf, certificate

My client have pre-printed certificates. Now, we want a dynamic run time certificate printing options as per matches schedules into the Match arranged.

One option I have seen at .Net guys help, they have generated PDF of scanned Certificate Image with PDF Writer and created textbox like to replace Name, txtName, then Date as txtDate etc for replacing dynamic values run time.

However with PHP/CakePHP, Any idea, how can we achieve the same logic with our requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install tcpdf, and explore more.

Create a template of pdf and all dynamic values replace with your cake values.

See image as background on tcpdf example. http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php [51]